# Position element absolutely, but to the right of another element

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a callout bubble to the right of some form fields using HTML and CSS. I don't want the callout effecting any other layout so I've got it positioned absolutely, but I'd like to somehow position it a certain distance to the right of another element.

This is basically what I have:

```
<ul>
    <dt><label>...</label></dt>
    <dd>
        <input ...>
        <span class='callout'>Helpful tip about this field</span>
    </dd>
</ul>
```

And:

```
.callout {
    position: absolute;
}
```

So I want the `.callout` out of the layout flow (hence `position:absolute`, but I want it positioned just to the right of the input field it's associated with (without knowing the width of the field in advance, of course).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to position it absolutely relative to your element. So, set your container to position: relative and your callout to position: absolute. Top/left then becomes the top left of the parent element. Make sense?

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/tNCDK/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent { 
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #000; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
}

#child { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -50px;
  border: solid 1px #000; 
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
}
```

​​

Comment: Please make your answer more "self-contained", by including the code, in case the jsFiddle link goes bad.

Comment: Of course. Sheesh, I should be better than that. Guess I was staring at the problem too long. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, I have a follow up question now, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516955/contain-floats-without-cutting-off-specific-items