# contain floats without cutting off specific items

Tags: html, css

FYI: This is a follow up to another question: [Position element absolutely, but to the right of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505516/position-element-absolutely-but-to-the-right-of-another-element/10505574#10505574)

I have a list of form elements and I'm trying to add callouts for each one. Each form entry has this general form:

```
<li>
    <input ...>
    <div class='callout'>Helpful description about form item.</div>
</li>
```

The `.callout` has `position:absolute` and the `LI`'s have `position:relative` so that the callout can be positioned "absolutely", relative to the LI.

That all works fine, but the problem is that one of the ancestors of the also contains some floats so I used the `overflow:hidden` trick on that to make sure it contains them. Unfortunately, that also means it's cutting off my callouts because they extend outside of it.

I guess a fallback is to drop an empty div at the end of that ancestor and just do `clear:both` on that, but is there a nicer CSS solution that will force the ancestor to contain the floats, but still allow absolutely positioned callouts to be visible outside the box?

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow: auto` instead?

Comment: why isnt a `clearfix` a nice css solution?

Comment: @tw16: `overflow:auto` just adds scrollbars when I try to show the tooltip, but then you'd have to scroll to actually see them.

@Benjamin: Turns out it's a very nice solution, I just wasn't aware of it. I didn't want to add a div to the HTML just to clear it, but the "virtual" element described in sandeep's answer below is very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `overflow:hidden` you can use **clearfix** method. Write like this:

```
li:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: If IE7 is a concern, it would be better to use the full thing: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Very cool, thanks. I tweaked it a little: I didn't want it to clear right after the LI per se, but I used `.panel:last-child:after` with those same style properties and it worked great (`.panel` is the class for the ancestor that I used to have `overflow:hidden` on).

I have the luxury of not having to care too much about IE7 or older. My philosophy is that if people want to use non-compliant browsers, I just suppress whatever goodies I can't make work easily. Fortunately, I don't have any actual clients to worry about.